# Ruby on rails checkbox conditional checked and disabled form content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm working on a project that was already coded, and I have to add some features. It simple, there is 5 days, for each days there is this organization:

[image: screenshot]

But I have a problem. in the original project, when user click on "Matin" for example, the inputs for hours are available for writing, and if it's not, the input box is disabled. Here is the code that work:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 check_<%= day %>_morning">
             <label style="font-weight: normal !important; color: #337ab7;">
             <% if !scheduler.object.morning_isEmpty? %>
             <%= check_box_tag day, 'yes', true, class: 'day_morning' %>
             <% else %>
             <%= check_box_tag day, 'yes', false, class: 'day_morning' %>
             <% end %>
             Matin</label>
           </div>

           <div class="all-scheduler col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 none-label <%= day %>_form_morning <% if scheduler.object.morning_isEmpty? %> disabledcontent <% end %>">

             <%= scheduler.input :begin_hour_morning, input_html: { type: 'number', min: 0, max: 23 }, class:  day + '_form_morning'  %>&nbsp;h&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <%= scheduler.input :begin_min_morning, input_html: { type: 'number', min: 0, max: 59 }, class: day + '_form_morning' %>
           </div>
           <div class="all-scheduler col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12 <%= day %>_form_morning day_form <% if scheduler.object.morning_isEmpty? %> disabledcontent <% end %>">
            <div class="mobile-slash"> /</div>
           </div>
           <div class="all-scheduler col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 none-label <%= day %>_form_morning <% if scheduler.object.morning_isEmpty? %>  disabledcontent  <% end %>">
             <%= scheduler.input :end_hour_morning, input_html: { type: 'number', min: 0, max: 23 }, class: day + '_form_afternoon' %>&nbsp;h&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <%= scheduler.input :end_min_morning, input_html: { type: 'number', min: 0, max: 59 }, class: day + '_form_afternoon' %>
           </div>
         </div>
         <br>
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-sm-2"></div>
           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 check_<%= day %>_rdv_morning <% if !scheduler.object.morning_isEmpty? %> disabledcontent <% end %>">
           <%= scheduler.check_box :morning_rdv, {class: 'rdv' } %>
           <label style="font-weight: normal !important; color: #337ab7;"> Matinée sur rendez-vous </label>
           </div>
         </div> <br> <br>
```

and the model:

```
  def morning_isEmpty?
     return (begin_hour_morning.nil? || begin_min_morning.nil? ||
        end_hour_morning.nil? || end_min_morning.nil?)
  end
```

and here is the code that I copy/paste from the previous code and doesn't work (when I check the "Journée complète" checkbox the field is still disabled):

```
             <div class="row space-allday">
         <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 check_<%= day %>_all_day">
           <label style="font-weight: normal !important; color: #337ab7;">
           <% if !scheduler.object.all_scheduler_is_empty? %>
           <%= check_box_tag day, 'yes', true, class: 'day_all' %>
           <% else %>
           <%= check_box_tag day, 'yes', false, class: 'day_all' %>
           <% end %>
           Journée complète</label>
         </div>

         <div class="all-scheduler col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 none-label <%= day %>_form_allday <% if scheduler.object.all_scheduler_is_empty? == true %>disabledcontent <% end %>">

           <%= scheduler.input :day_begin_hour, input_html: { type: 'number', min: 0, max: 23 }, class: day + '_form_allday'  %>&nbsp;h&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <%= scheduler.input :day_begin_min, input_html: { type: 'number', min: 0, max: 59 }, class: day + '_form_allday' %>
         </div>
         <div class="all-scheduler col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12 <%= day %>_form_allday day_form <% if scheduler.object.all_scheduler_is_empty? == true %>disabledcontent <% end %>">
           <div class="mobile-slash"> /</div>
         </div>
         <div class="all-scheduler col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 none-label <%= day %>_form_allday <% if scheduler.object.all_scheduler_is_empty? == true %>disabledcontent <% end %>">
           <%= scheduler.input :day_end_hour, input_html: { type: 'number', min: 0, max: 23 }, class: day + '_form_allday' %>&nbsp;h&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <%= scheduler.input :day_end_min, input_html: { type: 'number', min: 0, max: 59 }, class: day + '_form_allday' %>
         </div>
       </div>
       <br>
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-sm-2"></div>
         <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 check_<%= day %>_rdv_allday">
         <%= scheduler.check_box :day_rdv, :class => 'rdv' %>
         <label style="font-weight: normal !important; color: #337ab7;"> Journée sur rendez-vous </label>
         </div>
       </div>
```

and the model:

```
  def all_scheduler_is_empty?
return (day_begin_hour.nil? || day_begin_min.nil? ||
    day_end_hour.nil? || day_end_min.nil?)
```

end

Does someone could help me to improve the code and find the issue?

Comment: To me it looks like basically the same code, just that for Journée you entered another check <% if !scheduler.object.morning_isEmpty? %> in the first example

Comment: @KcUS_unico yes the code is the same but not the result, because when I click on the checkbox, the fields are still disabled, unlike the first code example

Comment: if those disable and enable dynamically while unchecking/checking the checkbox it will require JS, not only ruby

Comment: @mswiszcz in the example that work, there is no Javascript, the changes happened with `<%= day %>_form_morning <% if scheduler.object.morning_isEmpty? %>`

Comment: @mswiszcz my fault there is javascript, and I find the issue ! thank you !

Comment: Examples should be in English, not in French

Answer (score 0):

So..I don't have enough points to just comment and I'm not sure this will be the right answer but...
In the first code you have this line:

```
<% if scheduler.object.morning_isEmpty? %>
```

and in the second version you have:

```
<% if scheduler.object.all_scheduler_is_empty? == true %>
```

What happens when you do a double truth check? If the first way works, why add  == true ?